# how to insert the current date time as value in XML attriubute?

Tags: python, xml, datetime, xml-parsing

this is what i`m trying so far unles it exist a method that i can use for child4 ?

```
child4 = et.SubElement(child_second_element, 'order-date')
child4.text = datetime.datetime.now()
```

i want my xml to look like this

```
 <order-date>2020-08-21</order-date>
```

Comment: You are creating `element` - not `attribute`

Answer (score 0):

just got it

```
from datetime import datetime

date_time = datetime.now()
```